# get certain node from list of children firebase ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to retrieve a specific node in all my children and want to collect all the "role" in every child under "Users"

Here is the database setup:

```
 Users: 

      25TWFD7SLmQ3onRUdffvfx6Nfmw1:

            role: "officer"

      9OwM6FIPZgOKu3zzVYSrkPWR0Ij2

            role: "advisor"
```

How can I retrieve all of the "role" nodes?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please share that.

Answer (score 2):

here you can get the particular node "role".

```
//To get the all record

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
     ref.child("Users").childByAutoId().queryOrdered(byChild: "role").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
//To check the data
 guard let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
                return
                }
let keyArray = [String] (userDict.keys)
for key in keyArray {
            if var dataDict = userDict[key] as? [String:Any] {

                    self.userRoleArray.append(dataDict)

                    }
                }
      }
```

Hopefully this will work for you. 
happy coding...

Comment: How can I load all the results, all the "role"s, in an array

Comment: i have updated the code please check it ... if any issue feel free to raise your concern @codelover